# WordPress custom field from post comes out as string

Tags: wordpress, format, field, custom-fields

I'm using custom field for the index content coming from a post that has the custom fields, I'm new with WordPress so maybe that isn't the best way to do it. But I have them showing up now, the only problem is that even if I classified their type as WYSIWYG, they're coming out as strings.

Here's the code i found that works like this.

```
<?php
$custom_fields = get_post_custom(38);
$my_custom_field = $custom_fields['como_solicitar_nossos_servicos_home'];
foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value )
echo $value;
?>
```

Is there any way that i can get this field for example and make the html format keep?

I appreciate all the help I can get, thank you in advance

Comment: Are you using the default custom fields? Those don't have WYSIWYG... If not, show the code, or tell the plugin, you're using to handle the fields.

Comment: Hi, I'm using advanced custom fields, sorry didn't mention that

Comment: Solved, thanks anyway